# Error on boot from install disk - UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY

Tags: boot, system-installation

I'm getting the following error when i boot my PC from a USB that i burned with latest Ubuntu ISO image. I tried burning the USB twice using etcher and rufus just in case that process failed for some reason.

**Installing - ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64
Did a checksum verification and my ISO file is valid**

Any ideas?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2NXa.jpg)

Comment: Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?
  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
  Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
  http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.
  For other releases' hashes, like lubuntu, see:
  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Comment: You gave no release details (ie. what ISO you are using, as ISOs beyond 20.04 differ slightly than 20.04 or earlier, which can make a large difference), nor clues as to how you wrote the ISO to media (*if using a CLONE method all versions of writing software will work, but if using a reformat option on rufus etc on later than 20.04 you need updated software to successfully write the ISO*).  Is your ISO writing software updated & can cope with all write methods for your *unstated* Ubuntu product/release?

Comment: Looks like your filesystem is larger than the partition!  Maybe the partition was shrunk by a tool that didn't shrink the filesystem first, so run resize2fs on the partition and let it shrink the fs.

Answer (score 1):

I must have done the checksum wrong or used an old local file but I redownloaded and also used a SD card instead and it worked for me. Checking the checksums to validate the file was the initial step I missed.